# Python MySQLDB executemany() works on mac, does nothing on linux

Tags: python, mysql, linux, macos

I run a number of SQL scripts in this manner:

```
db_conn = (created earlier)
cursor  = db_conn.cursor()

script_file = open(join(script_path, script_name))
script_text = script_file.read()
script_file.close()

num_rows = cursor.executemany(script_text, None)
```

This works like a charm on my Mac, but fails on Linux, `executemany(...)` simply does nothing and returns `None`. Connection settings are fine: They are identical on both systems and I can execute the SQL scripts manually, i.e. using the mysql command line client. Also, `MySQLDB.execute(...)` works fine with shorter SQL statements, but then presumably fails on the changed delimiter in a stored procedure definition (reports an SQL error around the DELIMITER line anyway).

Has anyone ever come across something similar before ?
Is anyone using `executemany()` successfully on Linux ?

Versions:

- Mac OS X 10.6.4
- mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.39, for apple-darwin9.5.0 (i386) using readline 5.1
- MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal
- Kubuntu 10.10
- mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.49, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.1
- MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-linux-i686
  (the default Kubuntu package is 1.2.2, so I upgraded manually)

(for some reason, there's an extra empty line after Kubuntu 10.10 I can't seem to get rid of, possibly a stackoverflow bug...)

Comment: I use `executemany()`, but on a single SQL statement applied to many values (like `INSERT`). I don't know what is in your `script_text` variable. I've been doing it with 1.2.2 without any trouble on a linux system.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you upgraded properly to 1.2.3 ... I remember reading that 1.2.2 had a bug that caused problems with executemany.

Comment: No problem at all with `executemany` on 1.2.2 on linux. Been using it.

Comment: @Danosaure: Try an INSERT with some mysql function using executemany ... -> http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2137599&group_id=22307&atid=374932